# Can I include a MODULE-COMPLIANCE in the INCLUDES clause in AGENT-CAPABILITIES?

Tags: snmp, mib

As far as I understand the normal practice is to create object groups which are listed in MODULE-COMPLIANCE (this is done by the MIB designer), then the agent implementer describes the AGENT-CAPABILITIES with its VARIATIONs based on the groups used in single/multiple MODULE-COMPLIANCEs. The AGENT-CAPABILITIES is supposed to describe what the agent can do "compared" to the groups included in the MODULE-COMPLIANCE. What if the implementation fully complies with the MODULE-COMPLIANCE? Can I INCLUDE the MODULE-COMPLIANCE instead of listing all the groups it contains?

The snmpb validator and a couple of others do not raise any warnings.

```
xyzCompl MODULE-COMPLIANCE
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "Module Compliance"
    MODULE 
    MANDATORY-GROUPS { xyzFirstGroup, ... , xyzLastGroup }
    ::= { xyzCompanyCompl 1}

xyzAgent AGENT-CAPABILITIES
    PRODUCT-RELEASE "Agent release v1"
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION     "xyz Agent"

    SUPPORTS        XYZ-MIB

    -- what usually gets included
    INCLUDES        { xyzFirstGroup, ... , xyzLastGroup }
    -- what I want to include
    INCLUDES        { xyzCompl }

    ::= { xyzCompanyAgents 1 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explicitly legal for INCLUDES to reference OIDs other than OBJECT-GROUPs and NOTIFICATION-GROUPs in SMIv1 modules, per [RFC 2576 §2.3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2576.txt) (emphasis mine):

> In order to ease coexistence, object groups defined in an SMIv1
>      compliant MIB module may be referenced by the INCLUDES clause of an
>      invocation of the AGENT-CAPABILITIES macro:  upon encountering a
>      reference to an OBJECT IDENTIFIER subtree defined in an SMIv1 MIB
>      module, all leaf objects **which are subordinate to the subtree** and
>      have a STATUS clause value of mandatory are deemed to be INCLUDED.

The specs are silent with regards to INCLUDES referencing non-GROUP OIDs of SMIv2 modules, so it is somewhat ambiguous as to whether **INCLUDES { xyzCompl }** is legal.

On the one hand, with some exceptions SMIv2 modules can be converted to SMIv1 and vise versa, and converting from SMIv2 to SMIv1 xyzCompl would be converted to a simple **OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=** assignment, which would be indistinguishable from any other; that would imply it to be legal.

On the other hand, it specifies that only those objects with STATUS mandatory are deemed to be included. SMIv2 STATUS "current" is not the same thing as SMIv1 STATUS "mandatory" (although they are the closest things to each other; the "must implement" implication of "mandatory" is subsumed by MODULE-COMPLIANCE rules in SMIv2). This *could* be interpreted to mean they would not be included because their STATUS isn't "mandatory", or it *could* be interpreted that, since the MODULE-COMPLIANCE is specified in the SUPPORTS clause, and the MODULE-COMPLIANCE specifies what are mandatory groups, that this is sufficiently equivalent to STATUS mandatory as to be included.

**However**, per the emphasized bit in the quoted section of RFC 2576 all of this **only** applies if the OBJECT-TYPEs you are intending to specify as included have OID prefixes the same as your MODULE-COMPLIANCE OID, which is very much not recommended and is also unlikely, and so it's all kind of moot: unless your OBJECT-TYPEs are OID children of xyzCompl, they're not included, despite being members of groups you've specified in MANDATORY-GROUPS!

Conclusion: it is legal syntax, hence there is no complaint, but it is unlikely to be specifying what you are intending it to. Without seeing the rest of the MIB, I would say that this AGENT-CAPABILITIES would be saying it SUPPORTS XYZ-MIB while also not supporting any objects from XYZ-MIB if it uses **INCLUDES { xyzCompl }**.

Comment: Dear Michael Thank You for taking your time to respond to a 3-year-old post! As far as I remember I had 4 similar devices with interlocking capabilities. I wanted to modularize the design to increase the readability of the capabilities of the agent.